# How to create a view from table row values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
ID  |  staff_id  |  Meta_key  | Meta_Value  | Meta_Group
1          1         landline      456          contact
2          1          mobile       777          contact
3          1          email      i@i.i          contact
4          2         landline      453          contact
5          2          mobile       888          contact
6          2          email      d@i.i          contact
```

I want to create a view called view_contact_details that looks like this:

```
 staff_id  |  landline  |  mobile  | email
    1          456          777      i@i.i
    2          453          888      d@i.i
```

Is this possible to do? I appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a CASE wrapped in a MAX

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID int, staff_id int, meta_key varchar(10), meta_value varchar(10), meta_group varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, staff_id, meta_key, meta_value, meta_group)
VALUES
(1,1,'landline','456','contact')
,(2,1,'mobile','777','contact')
,(3,1,'email','i@i.i','contact')
,(4,2,'landline','453','contact')
,(5,2,'mobile','888','contact')
,(6,2,'email','d@i.i','contact')
```

Query;

```
CREATE VIEW view_contact_details
AS
SELECT
Staff_ID
,MAX(CASE WHEN Meta_Key = 'landline' THEN Meta_Value END) Landline
,MAX(CASE WHEN Meta_Key = 'mobile' THEN Meta_Value END) Mobile
,MAX(CASE WHEN Meta_Key = 'email' THEN Meta_Value END) Email
FROM #TestData
GROUP BY staff_id
```

Results;

```
Staff_ID    Landline    Mobile  Email
1           456         777     i@i.i
2           453         888     d@i.i
```